# How does Advaita Vedanta assert and prove the eternality of cognition of Non dual Atman?

Tags: advaita, upanishads, atma, buddhism, consciousness

This article [1] says

> Śāntarakṣita has however refuted the Upanishadic non-dualism in the
> Tattva Sangraha’ chapter 7, section 5. In his refutation of the
> Upanishadic view he has referred to the followers of the Upanishad as
> those who postulate that the âtmà is eternal, one and of the nature of
> knowledge/conciousness/ Jñànasvaråpa. Kamalaśīla has also commented on
> this view describing it as, “That is the âtmà is of the nature of one
> eternal consciousness / knowledge.” **“The error in the view of these
> philosophies is a slight one – due only to the assertion of eternality
> of cognition.”**

How can Advaita Vedanta prove eternal Atman as consciouness existing always?
[1]: https://www.byomakusuma.org/VedantaVisAVisShentong.html

Comment: I would think that Brahman is ever aware of itself and merged in itself. Impersonal. I may be wrong. Pls correct if needed.

Comment: Yes Brahman is Swaprakasha(Self-luminous) @ajitdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prof Chandradhar Sharma on Critical Survey of Indian Philosophy, Page 312 writes,

> A momentary idea can be neither self-luminous nor can it ideate
> itself. The reality of permanent self-luminous Self which is Pure
> Consciousness must be admitted. **Vedanta criticizes only their
> momentary vijnanas and their view that external world is unreal
> because it is a projection of momentary consciousness as this view
> well smacks of subjectivism when consciousness is reduced to momentary
> ideas.** Vedanta points out that the arguments which the
> Svatantra-Vijnänavädins advance against permanent consciousness are
> more applicable to their own momentary consciousness. To take an
> example, **if bondage and liberation are impossible when conscious is
> treated as permanent they are more so when consciousness is taken as
> momentary.** Vedänta accepts that Consciousness is Self-luminous and that
> it ultimately transcends the subject-object duality and the trinity of
> knowledge, knower and known and all the categories of the intellect.
> But from the empirical standpoint, stresses Vedänta, it is far better
> to describe Reality as Permanent and Pure Consciousness which is at
> once Pure Existence and Pure Bliss, **than to call it momentary for
> whatever is momentary is miserable and self-contradictory. The
> momentary vijnäna can be neither self-luminous nor can it ideate
> itself.** It requires the Pure Self which is Pure Consciousness to know
> it. Vedänta may well rejoin: The view of the Svatantra-Vijnänavädins
> is very much similar to Vedänta ; it contains very little error, its
> only fault is that it declares consciousness to be momentary.

In page 253, he continues,

> The antecedent link in the causal series, says Shankara, cannot even
> be regarded as the efficient cause of the subsequent link because,
> according to the theory of momentariness, the preceding link ceases to
> exist when the subsequent link arises. If it is urged that the
> antecedent moment when fully developed (parinispannâvasthah) becomes
> the cause of the subsequent moment, it is untenable, because the
> assertion that a fully developed moment has a causal efficiency
> necessarily presupposes its connection with the second moment and this
> repudiates the theory of universal momentariness. Again, if it is
> urged (as is done by the Svatantra-Vijnänavädins) that the mere
> existence of the preceding moment means its causal efficiency (bhâva
> evâsya vyâpârah),this too is impossible, because no effect can arise
> without imbibing the nature of the cause and to admit this is to admit
> that the cause is permanent as it continues to exist in the effect and
> thus to throw overboard the doctrine of momentariness.